# In this context "Possibly" is modifying what?

Tags: word-usage, adverbs, modifiers

*It's a possibly dangerous situation.*

I think "possibly" modifies the adjective "dangerous" or "dangerous situation",

doesit(possibly)indicate manner?

I found a definition of possibly " in a possible manner", But how can I use the definition as it is in the sentence??

Comment: _It is possible that the situation may involve some danger._ Think of _possibly_ as meaning _perhaps_.

Comment: I think most native speakers would put ***possibly*** either immediately after the verb *(**It's**)*, OR at the beginning or end of the utterance. And I don't think in practice it makes any difference to the overall meaning, so imho ***possibly*** here is a ***"whole sentence" adverb*** (i.e. - *perhaps* this utterance is true). Picking out a specific *word* for it to be "modifying" is a fairly pointless activity, that has no real semantic significance.

Comment: You can paint yourself into a corner asking which particular word an adverb modifies. There's often no reason to approach a sentence in that way. 

The word **possibly** could be thought of as modifying the assertion "is dangerous". 

Then we could debate whether the speaker is *conceding* that it isn't guaranteed to be dangerous, or offering an evaluation of the probability of the danger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possibly is a *'modifier of uncertainty'** [a term I just made up.]

Like 'potentially', 'perhaps', 'might' or 'maybe' it's one of those words** someone uses when they think or estimate a situation has a chance of being, in this case, dangerous, without any degree of absolute certainty.

They therefore restrain their utmost fear "It's a dangerous situation" by introducing one of these modifiers; thereby taking the pressure off them to be absolutely certain it's dangerous & reducing it to 'I think it might be' dangerous.

> I'm going to climb that ladder.
> That's *[a possibly/a potentially/perhaps a/may be a/might be a]* dangerous situation.

**From comments* - apparently the proper term for this is ['linguistic hedge'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hedge_(linguistics))

***Also:*
probably, likely.
<sup>I'll add to this as I think of them.</sup>

Comment: I'd say inserting ***possibly*** (and in my case here, ***'d = would***) are [*linguistic **hedges.***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hedge_(linguistics)) (But I understand your *'modifier of uncertainty'* to mean exactly that anyway, so have an upvote! :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers Ah - I kind of thought it was common enough it ought to have a proper term… I just had no clue where to start to look for it. Thanks, I'll add it to the answer.

Comment: Ah. So you're gonna just ignore my hedge, and quote me as "an authority", are you? Well, if someone else more knowledgeable than me (of whom I've no doubt there are *plenty* here on ELL! :) pops up to say that's *not* the right term, I'll blame it on you! Of course, the word ***apparently*** in your edit is effectively a hedge too - without hedges, none of us would ever dare say anything!

Comment: @FumbleFingers - I'd hesitate to contradict you, but there's a small hint of an insinuation of the potential possibility that we may, contra to expectation, both, in the end, turn out to be perhaps right… or indeed, perhaps, wrong. ;) [I really need the scriptwriter from "Yes, Minister" to get that to Sir Humphrey levels of …potential…ambiguity.]